# jquery Fancybox height is not changing at runtime

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I have a fancybox based image upload application. In the first step when I clickd a button labled "uoload photo" it displays a fancybox with a file upload field and a submit button. On submitting it displays the uploaded image for edititing. But what I want is to change the height of fancy box larger to wrap the uploaded image. 
I used

```
$.fancybox.resize()
```

and tried these things [How do you resize Fancybox at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/994876/jquery-fancybox-resize) which also did not help me.

Comment: also I did these but could not work.
`$('#fancybox-content').css('height','600px');
   $('#fancybox-outer').css('height','600px');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the fancybox version, you should probably use $.fancybox.update()

This question is similar to: [Auto height resizing in Fancybox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10996212/auto-height-resizing-in-fancybox)