# fancybox auto height iframe

Tags: jquery, html, fancybox

I need to know how can I set auto height(as long as the content height) of fancybox of type 'iframe'?

I tried this little piece of code, but it's not working

```
<a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" href="">Open Fancybox</a>

 $(".fancybox").fancybox({


                autoSize: true,
                autoHeight: true,
                autoWidth: true,
                fitToView: false,
                padding: 0,
                href: $(this).attr('href'),
                type: 'iframe',

            });
```

Comment: [this may help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10996212/auto-height-resizing-in-fancybox)

Comment: I already checked this out, but that doesn't work at all.

Comment: So you tried adding the beforeShow function to your options? you may want to make sure all your options are valid and you don't have any js errors (I see you have an extra comma at the end of the above options).  Also make sure your fancybox selector within the function is correct.  I used this and it worked fine for me - what version of fancybox are you using?

Comment: Yes, I used the beforeShow function. But I got this error in browser after I put this function "Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:32099" from accessing a frame with origin "iframe url". Protocols, domains, and ports must match."   PS: I removed the extra comma from the fancybox script.

Comment: I am using version 2.1.5

Comment: That sounds more like a [same origin error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript)

Comment: Aren't you missing anything in your link `href=""`??

Comment: No, the proper link is there in href tag. I couldn't find out any solution.