# close fancybox and open new one using functions

Tags: php, jquery, iframe, fancybox

I have an application where I am using Fancyboxes to display content from the server through IFRAMES within the Fancyboxes.  So, I am looking to run a script after data is submitted or changed in the server that calls the current fancybox with IFRAME to close and open another fancybox with a new url, size, and iframe inside of it.

I have tried several different codes through various googled sites, but none have worked for my app.

Help would be greatly appreciated!

UPDATE: Found the answer here: http://www.amitpatil.me/fancybox-runtime-resizing-of-iframe/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `$.fancybox.close` or `parent.$.fancybox.close()` (from iframe), and open a new one:

```
$.fancybox({            
'transitionIn'  : 'none',
'transitionOut' : 'none',
'width'     : 680,
'height'        : 495,
'href'      : 'http://example.com/new'
});
```

or simply resize fancybox: $.fancybox.resize().
This will help you in resizing: [How do you resize Fancybox at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/994876/jquery-fancybox-resize)

[UPDATE]

As I understand: You have A.php opened with fancybox. On A.php you probably have a form, and the form is submitted to B.php. If this is the situation, you have to close+open OR just resize the fancybox in the document.ready of B.php by parent.$.fancybox.function_name.

Comment: thanks for the quick answers.  I was searching for a resize at first, don't know why I didn't come across that link.

Comment: Glad to help you! If the answer was helping you solve the problem, please consider accepting the answer.

Comment: sorry, but just to get this straight, after my PHP actions are called and everything is sent to the database, I just call parent.$.fancybox.close() to close the fancybox, and then I place the other code in the parent page and it will automatically open a new fancybox?

Comment: that makes sense.  I figured that would be the case.  I like the resize option better either way.  It's much cleaner!

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you've tried this, but seems to work for me:

```
parent.MyFunction(); // call this from the iframed url

function MyFunction(){ // have this in your parent page
    // call your fancybox close function here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The method suggested by @TamasPap didn't work for me, and since I'd spent hours researching and experimenting until I finally found a method which worked, I wanted to share it.

```
parent.$.fancybox.open({ href : 'iframe2.html', type: 'iframe'});
parent.$.fancybox.close({ href : 'iframe1.html'});
```

You can specify any options, helpers or css after type: 'iframe' in the same manner you would when creating the function.