# How to adjust width of fancybox2 when it's already visible

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I have a fancybox that is shown when a user clicks a button.

The fancybox initially has 1 dropdown menu and depending on what the user clicks, different form elements are shown. The problem is the fancybox is only wide enough for the initial dropdown and it just has scroll bars once the form elements are shown instead of resizing.

How can I resize the fancybox in this scenario?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $('#clickme').fancybox();

        $('#substrate').change(function() {
            $this = $(this);

            if($this.val() != 'select') {


                if($this.val() == 'metal') {
                    console.log('$this = '+$this.val()); 
                    $('#ribConf').show();
                    $('#rust').show();
                    $('#fancyform').show();
                }

            } else {
                $('#fancyform').hide();
            }
        });

    });


<a id="clickme" href="#fancybox">click me</a>

        <div id="fancybox" style="display:none;">

            <p>
                <label for="substrate">Substrate</label>
                <select id="substrate" name="substrate">
                    <option value="select" selected="selected">-- Select --</option>
                    <option value="metal">Metal</option>
                    <option value="singleply">Single-Ply</option>
                    <option value="asphalt">Asphalt</option>
                </select>
            </p>

            <form id="fancyform" style="display:none;">

                <p>
                    <label for="squareFeet">Square Feet</label>
                    <input type="text" name="squareFeet" />
                </p>

                <p>
                    <label for="square">Square</label>
                    <input type="text" name="square" readonly="readonly"/>
                </p>

                <p id="ribConf" style="display:none;">
                    <label for="ribConf">Rib Configuration</label>
                    <input type="text" name="ribConf" />
                </p>

                <p id="rust" style="display:none;">
                    <label for="rust">Rust</label>
                    <input type="text" name="rust" />
                </p>

                <p id="waste" style="display:none;">
                    <label for="waste">Waste</label>
                    <input type="text" name="waste" />
                </p>

                <p><input id="submit" type="submit" value="Calculate"/></p>

            </form>
        </div>
```

Comment: Is this what you are looking for ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/994876/jquery-fancybox-resize ; cheers

Comment: Not exactly because if i do this if($this.val() == 'metal') {
                    console.log('$this = '+$this.val()); 
                    $('#ribConf').show();
                    $('#rust').show();
                    $('#fancyform').show();
                    $.fancybox.resize();
                }   It doesn't resize the fancybox and gives me an error.

Comment: Oh god. That's an error on my part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will work for you. I'm setting the size of the fancybox to force auto for both height and width. check out this test [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VaB4x/2/).

```
.fancybox-inner{width:auto!important; height:auto!important;}
.fancybox-outer{width:auto!important; height:auto!important;}​
```

You'll notice that there's an afterShow method to simulate dynamically added content

```
afterShow: function(){
        $('.fancybox-inner').append('<br/><br/><br/> testing stuff</br>')
    }
```

[this is probably a better link to view it in action](http://fiddle.jshell.net/VaB4x/2/show/)

Comment: Does this work if the width needs to increase or just the height? Also, how did you get that full screen test in jsfiddle?

Comment: both width and height should work. If you inspect the prewview elements in jsfiddle,and you;ll see a link to the iframe that renders the preview. that's the link

Comment: Is there a way to re-center the fancybox after the new content is added?

Comment: Ah i found it. calling $.fancybox.update(); re-centers the box. And just an fyi, with fancybox2, you need to add .fancybox-wrap to your css with the same attributes as you've added to inner and outer and it works perfect.