# fancyBox on WordPress Resize onWindow Resize

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I am using a fancyBox plugin for WordPress and I have an issue. When I resize the window the pop-up doesn't resize, but If I navigate through the images with the window resized it properly resizes the pop-up. I am trying to make an extra Callback like this:

```
window.onresize = function(event) {
   $.fancybox.resize();
}
```

But it displays an error: `$ is not defined`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `jQuery` instead of `$`

```
window.onresize = function(event) {
   jQuery.fancybox.resize();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`$(window).resize()`](http://api.jquery.com/resize/) and not `window.onresize`, as using native event handlers can interfere or be interfered with by jQuery. So use the jQuery methods if you have jQuery.

I don't know what version of FancyBox you have<sup>**$**</sup>, but if you're on the latest (2.1.0), you can pass [**`autoDimensions: true`**](http://fancybox.net/api) to the constructor and it will do it for you:

> **autoDimensions:** *true*
>   For inline and ajax views, resizes the view to
>   the element recieves. Make sure it has dimensions otherwise this will
>   give unexpected results

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a").fancybox({
        openEffect: 'none',
        closeEffect: 'none',
        width: 400,
        height: 300,
        autoDimensions: true
    });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yw4y5/), [Source](http://jsfiddle.net/yw4y5/embedded/result/)

You can also use one or more of the following:

```
 Method                 Description
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 $.fancybox.resize  // Auto-resizes FancyBox height to match content height
 $.fancybox.center  // Centers FancyBox in viewport
```

---

<sub><sup>**$**</sup> According to [this answer from 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2505274/451969), `$.fancybox.resize()` was for v1.3 and below. However, it is actually referenced in the latest (September 19, 2012) docs, down at [the very bottom](http://fancybox.net/api) under *Public Methods*.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this...

```
JQuery(document).ready(function() {

  window.onresize = function(event) {
    JQuery('.fancybox').resize();
  }

)};
```

The `.fancy` is a class correct?